# arm llvm assembly q and v registers

Tags: assembly, optimization, arm

In the following code generated by xcode, you see in the first 2 lines that the values are loaded to `q0` and `q1` registers, but used from the `v0` and `v1` registers, why not using also `q0` and `q1` instead of `v0` and `v1`.

Are `v0` and `v1` alias of `q0` and `q1` (source: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch04s06s02.html )?

```
0x100005db0 <+548>:  ldr    q0, [x9, x12]
0x100005db4 <+552>:  ldr    q1, [x10, x12]
0x100005db8 <+556>:  cmeq.4s v2, v0, v4
0x100005dbc <+560>:  bsl.16b v2, v1, v0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The names `v0` and `q0` refer to the same register.  The difference lies in how the register content is interpreted:  The name `q0` indicates that the register is interpreted as a single 128 bit quantity while the name `v0` indicates that the register is interpreted as a vector of something.  The type of the vector elements is indicated by a suffix to the instruction mnemonic.  In your case, `.4s` indicates a vector of four 32 words (32 bit quantities) whereas `.16b` indicates a vector of 16 octets (eight bit quantities).  The specific details of this notation are explained in the documentation you already linked to.